# Checkbox Click not in sync -Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a table with checkbox and text input column. The last row in the checkbox column has a "Check All" link.

Upon Check All click:

1: Text must change "Uncheck All"

2: Check the box above in the column and set textbox text = 500.

Upon "Uncheck All":
1: Text must change "Check All"
2: Uncheck the box and clear the textbox.

But point 2 above is not working properly.

Steps:

1: Click "Check All" - Text changes to "Uncheck All" and box is checked but it does not set the Textbox to 500.

2: Click "Uncheck All" - Text Changes to "Check All" and box is unchecked but now it sets the textbox to 500.

I think it is some event handling issue but I haven't figured it out so far.

Any ideas what's going on?

**Note:** I will have to use "onclick" because my actual code is .aspx page which doesn't recognize onchange with checkbox.

**Updated code** [Sample](http://jsbin.com/inocud/14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function onClick() and setValue() runs before click() applies a check on to the checkbox;
Therefore at step 1, it does not see the check box checked.

Comment: Yes, I set alerts and kind of understand that but how do I fix it now.

Comment: Here's the correct approach and a solution. http://jsbin.com/inocud/20/edit (I edit as minimal as possible for you to understand.. The code can be further optimized).  Also you should upvote for the correct answer even if no one provide a fix to your code.

Comment: Haven't looked at your code completely but has some side-effects. If I don't set .attr("checked","checked") in CheckAll click it will set all check to unchecked and unchecked to checked. So have to even maintain that.

Comment: Ahh forgot about that case. All you gotta do is to verify it before allowing it to click. This should do it http://jsbin.com/inocud/25/

Comment: Thanks. You solution is taking me forward but need to tweak to make it fully work in my complex scenario. I am still working on it.

Comment: I did a lot of tweaking to your last code and got it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

changed 'checked' to be boolean and is fine.

**updated** http://jsbin.com/inocud/16

class approach - http://jsbin.com/inocud/22

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. Also see my post above. I have updated the code sample.

Comment: Geez. quite illogic, but inverse the checkbox check to !chb.checked and it seems to work from the very start. http://jsbin.com/inocud/16 and seems like checked attribute is extra since it gets checked anyway so perhaps it gets doubleinversed in some point

Comment: Ahhh...Thanks. Why did that work for you? I tried that exact !chb.checked logic but was behaving the original way. I will play around a bit and will close this if I don't see any other side-effects.

Comment: Oh and I don't think it is getting doubleinversed but it is the order in which setValue and onclick is called as pointed out by jason.

Comment: Ok I see why  !chb.checked didn't work for me and will not work  because using that will break the click on the checkbox itself.

Comment: Here is another approach i created by using classes. so it will not get confusing with checkboxes http://jsbin.com/inocud/22

Comment: Thanks. Will have to look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Attempted a shot.

**Updated** (Its a hack but works): http://jsfiddle.net/2YGYt/

**Another method** (non hacky way): http://jsfiddle.net/2YGYt/3/

Comment: No I can't set it there. There are many rows. It has to be set from setValue because onclick is added as Attribute from code-behind in asp.net. So the value 500 will be different for each checkboxes in the column.

Comment: Then just switch the order of your `click` and `.attr` - See here: http://jsbin.com/inocud/13/edit

Comment: I already tried that but no luck. And do check my updated sample to get better idea of my scenario.

Comment: Added another way, which uses jQuery `data` proeprty bag.

Comment: I tried your final version that didn't work especially when you just click on the checkbox but I have got it working. Thanks for the try.

Comment: With the non-hack-way click a checkbox. It doesn't populate anything in the textbox. And with the hackway click one checkbox and then click CheckAll. It just inverses the selection.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. Need to do some extran handling in `setValue`. Have you got it working? If not, I can give it a try.

Comment: Yeah I got it working the way I wanted using jason's sample as base.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script> 
 $(function () {
            $(".checkall").click(function () {


                if ($(this).text() == "Check All") {
                    $(this).text("Uncheck All");
                    $(this).parent().parent().prevUntil('tbody').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td input:checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked').click();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).text("Check All");
                    $(this).parent().parent().prevUntil('tbody').each(function () {
                        $(this).find("td input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked').click();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        function setValue(chb, txtid, valu) {
            if ($(chb).is(":checked")) {
                $("#" + txtid).val(valu);
            }
            else {
                $("#" + txtid).val("");
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: The issue was you are setting the checked attribute after calling click method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work either. It just reverses the behavior of checkbox and textbox.